Tailwind CSS styles are not taking effect during unit testing
Technology Stack:

vite
react
vitest
testing-library/react
testing-library/jest-dom

Test
// test/comment.test.jsx
import { it, expect } from "vitest";
import { screen, render } from "@testing-library/react";
import { userEvent } from "@testing-library/user-event";
import CommentTitle from "../components/Comment/CommentTitle";

it("There should be a sorting icon, which upon hovering, displays a list containing two items: Hottest First and Newest First. Beside the icon, there's text reading 'Sort'.", async () => {
  const user = userEvent.setup();
  render(<CommentTitle commentListLength={0} />);

  expect(screen.queryByText("sort")).not.toBeNull();

  const sortByIcon = screen.queryByTestId("sort-by-icon");
  expect(sortByIcon).not.toBeNull();
  expect(screen.queryByText("Hottest First")).not.toBeVisible();
  expect(screen.queryByText("Newest First")).not.toBeVisible();
  await user.hover(sortByIcon);
  expect(screen.queryByText("Hottest First")).toBeVisible();
  expect(screen.queryByText("Newest First")).toBeVisible();
});

Manually, the test should not fail, yet the automated test fails at the second expectation.
Using screen.logTestingPlaygroundURL(), I found that some Tailwind CSS styles aren't applying. The test passes for the initial state when I set an inline style of display: none, but it still fails afterward (since I can't apply pseudo-classes to inline styles).
Component
// src/components/CommentTitile.jsx
import Proptypes from "prop-types";
import { MdSort } from "react-icons/md";
function CommentTitle({ commentListLength }) {
  return (
    <div
      data-testid="comment-title"
      className="flex flex-row items-center gap-6 mb-20 "
    >
      <span data-testid="number-of-comments">
        comments{commentListLength || ""}
      </span>
      <div className="flex flex-row gap-2 items-center">
        <div className="flex flex-row items-center relative cursor-pointer">
          <div className="self-start text-lg peer" data-testid="sort-by-icon">
            <MdSort />
          </div>
          <ul className="peer-hover:block hidden absolute rounded  whitespace-pre top-6 left-1/2 -translate-x-1/2 p-2">
            <li>Hottest First</li>
            <li>Newest First</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div data-testid="sort-text">sort</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
...

Adding the configuration still doesn't resolve the issue.
// testSetup.js
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/vitest";
import "./src/index.css";  // add that line

// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  test: {
    setupFiles: "./testSetup.js",
    globals: true,
    environment: "jsdom",
    css: true,    // add that line
  },
});

Addtitions:

codesandbox
github


Hey after looking at this other post and because you don't show the content of your src/index.css, I'd recommend trying to add these lines to see if it adds the necessary css for the tests.
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

I'm just wondering if you encounter another issue entirely because you said that some styles are not applying when using the debug log.
